# mac os x mavericks (10.9) location of ssh log

Tags: macos, mac

I am looking for the location of the log file that shows failed + successful ssh logins. I am trying to determine any IP addresses to block.

Comment: As a heads-up: there are pre-made scripts that might achieve what you're looking for, like [sshblack](http://www.pettingers.org/code/sshblack.html) for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The information will be in `/var/log/system.log`

In Lion and earlier versions of OS X, the file is `/var/log/secure.log`